# how to get right alignment for section and subsection in the table of contents in latex for arabic language?

Tags: alignment, arabic

I am using Arabic language so the alignment should be from the right to left.

What I have so far for the table of contents is:

[image]

and I have three problems:

1. the roman numbering doesn't apply for the pages before chapter 1 (المبحث ١: علوم الحاسوب)
2. The right alignment for the section and subsection is wrong and I tried all the solutions on this website and couldn't fix it.
3. I want to change the chapter numbering to alphabetical one. Instead of chapter 1, I wanted chapter one. In my case for the Arabic version, instead of (المبحث ١) I want (المبحث الأول).

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage{tocloft}


\usepackage{titletoc}%
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
[0pt]% <left>
{\bfseries}% <above-code>
{\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>




\addto\captionsarabic{%
\renewcommand\chaptername{المبحث}
}

\addto{\captionsarabic}{\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{قائمة المحتويات}}



\title{
\Huge\textsc{اللغة العربية}
}
 \author{سالم البوزيدي} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\pagenumbering{roman}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{5}

\chapter*{الملخص}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{الملخص}



\chapter*{شكر وثناء}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{شكر وثناء}


\chapter*{اهداء}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{اهداء}


\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter{علوم الحاسوب}
\section{تاريخ}


\subsection{تاريخ}
\section{تاريخ}
\subsection{تاريخ}
\subsection{تاريخ}


\chapter{علوم الحاسوب}

\chapter{علوم الحاسوب}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
[1]
من ويكيبيديا، الموسوعة الحرة
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I appreciate any help in this.

EDIT: My code now after the  Pieter van Oostrum suggenstion is:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} %Same
   \usepackage{fontspec} % Added
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % Added%Use    "Ligatures=TeX"     instead of "Mapping=tex-text"
   \usepackage{polyglossia}% Added
    \setdefaultlanguage{arabic}% Added
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}% Added

     \usepackage{lipsum} %Same
      \usepackage{setspace}%Same
      \usepackage{titlesec}%Same
       \usepackage{tocloft}%Same

      \usepackage{geometry} %Same
      \geometry{
      a4paper,
      total={170mm,257mm},
      left=25mm,
      right=25mm,
      top=30mm,
      bottom=30mm,
     }

   \usepackage{biblatex}  %Same
   \addbibresource{sample.bib}  %Same

   \usepackage{graphicx}  %Same
   \usepackage{tikz}  %Same
   \usepackage{eso-pic}  %Same
   \usepackage{atbegshi,picture}  %Same
   \usepackage{array,graphicx,lipsum}  %Same
   \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  %Same
   \usepackage{titling}  %Same


   %\TOCLanguage{arabic} % arabic is the main language 
   %\newcommand\lr[1]{\textLR{#1}}
   %\newcommand\rl[1]{\textRL{#1}}


   \makeatletter
   \def\ps@plain{\ps@empty\SAV@ps@plain}
   \makeatletter
   \pagestyle{plain}




    \newcommand\numberstring[1]{%   %Same
    \ifcase #1
    % zero
    \or الأول%
    \or الثاني%
    \or الثالث%
    \or الرابع%
    \or الخامس%
    \else I don't know%
    \fi
     }

    %\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\numberstring{\c@chapter}}
    %\makeatother

    \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-3em}

     \usepackage{titletoc}%
    \titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
    [0pt]% <left>
    {\bfseries}% <above-code>
    {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
    {}% <numberless-entry-format>
     {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
     \titlecontents{section}
                  [0pt]
                  {}
                  {\thecontentslabel {  } }
                  {}
                  {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
    \titlecontents*{subsection}
                  [0pt]
                  {}
                  {\thecontentslabel{  }}
                  {}
                  {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}



    \addto\captionsarabic{%
    \renewcommand\chaptername{المبحث}
    }

   \addto{\captionsarabic}{\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{قائمة المحتويات }}

    \usepackage{titling}
    \newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
     \posttitle{%
     \par\end{center}
     \begin{center}\large#1 \end{center}
      \vskip0.5em}%
      }
     \newcommand{\subsubtitle}[1]{%
     \preauthor{%
     \begin{center}
     \large #1 \vskip0.5em
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
       }%
      }




   \makeatletter         
   \def\@maketitle{
   \raggedright
    \includegraphics[width = 40mm]{logo.png}\\[8ex]
     }
   \makeatother



    %\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}}



    \newlength{\myspace}
     \setlength{\myspace}{10em}

     \makeatletter
      \xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip.5em}{\vskip\myspace}{}{}
      \makeatother

        \AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
         \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax,-1.5cm){\makebox[0pt]    [r]{\framebox{

     \\جمهورية العراق
     \\ وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
     \\ الجامعة العراقية
     \\ كلية الادارة والاقتصاد
  
  
    }}}%
    }}



      \begin{document}



    \begin{titlepage}

     \begin{center}



            
       \vspace*{1cm}
       \begin{center}

      \Large{  أثر المعرفة في تعزيز
            الميزة التنافسية}

       \vspace{0.5cm}
             \large
              بحث مقدم الى مجلس كلية الادارة والاقتصاد-   
              الجامعة العراقية وهو جزء من متطلبات نيل شهادة البكالوريوس في الادارة           والاقتصاد - قسم ادارة الاعمال    

        
      \vspace{1.5cm}
   
     اعداد الطالب\\
      \text{مصطفى محمد عفر}\\
       \vspace*{2cm}
       باشراف

      \text{ م . د وسن سعد }

     \vfill
   
     \vspace{1cm}
 
   
     ٢٥ نيسان ٢٠٢١
   
     \end{center}
   
        
     \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    %٪\maketitle

   \newpage


    \pagenumbering{Roman}
     \renewcommand{\thepage}{\protect\textLR{\Roman{page}}}

    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}



     \tableofcontents




     %\usepackage{titlesec}
     \titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}


     \newpage
      \doublespacing
      \begin{doublespace}
      \input{الملخص}
      \end{doublespace}


        \newpage
         \doublespacing
          \begin{doublespace}
          \input{المقدمة}
           \end{doublespace}

           \newpage
           \doublespacing
           \begin{doublespace}
            \input{الاية القرانية}
             \end{doublespace}

          \newpage
           \doublespacing
          \begin{doublespace}
           \input{شكر وثناء}
            \end{doublespace}


           \newpage
           \doublespacing
          \begin{doublespace}
         \input{اهداء.tex}
           \end{doublespace}

           \pagenumbering{arabic}
           %\renewcommand{\thepage}{\protect          \textLR{\arabic{page}}}


            \newpage
            \doublespacing
             \begin{doublespace}
              \input{المبحث الأول}
              \end{doublespace}


              \begin{thebibliography}{99}


              \end{thebibliography}


                  \end{document}


                    %------------------------
```

My problem now is the Chapter numbering doesn't match the section numbering. I wanted before to change the chapter number to letter instead like chapter 1 to Chapter One and I succeeded in that applying Pieter van Oostrum suggestion but now I am having another problem which is the section numbering is also converted to the letters like 1.1 is converted to One.1 and I don't want this behavior. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: It might have something to do with `arabic` changing page styles. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587259

Comment: You want section and subsection numbers in the TOC, using alphabetical numbering, like the chapters not stared?

Comment: I you put `\pagenumbering{arabic}  % move here <<<<` AFTER `\chapter{<the first>}` it works as you wanted. See my example where `\chapter{Introduce}` is the first numbered chapter. page 1. Before that every  page is with roman numbering.

Comment: The Arabic numbering works fine, but before the chapters, the number is still Arabic too. I have like 1, 2, 3, then restart at chapter page to 1, 2, 3, and so on.

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the first two problems are caused by `arabtex` and `babel`. For some reason the page numbers are written to the `.aux` and `.toc` files without any formatting. That is the reason it doesn't use roman numbering. And anyway, the `\pagenumbering{roman}` should be done before the `\tableofcontents` just in case that takes more than one page. Also there must be a `\clearpage` or `\newpage` before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

I would suggest to forget `arabtex` and `babel`, and instead run `XeTeX` and `polyglossia` instead.

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
```

The third problem could have been solved by `fmtcount`, as @Simon Dispa writes, but that doesn't support Arabic, unfortunately. You could try to make a copy, for example of the Spanish or French files, but that would be a lot of work. As you need only a few numbers, I think you can do it yourself, see the following code and replace the English words with Arabic ones.

```
\newcommand\numberstring[1]{%
  \ifcase #1
  % zero
  \or one%
  \or two%
  \or three%
  \or four%
  \or five%
  \or six%
  \or seven%
  \else I don't know%
  \fi
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\numberstring{\c@chapter}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I switched to XeLatex as you said and it works better with me. regarding the third problem, I applied what you wrote, it works with the chapter heading like Chapter 1 is converted to Chapter One, but there is another problem that happened which is the subtitle under it also converted to an aliphatic ones, like ( 1.1) is converted to (One.1) and I don't want this behavior, is there any solution for this

Comment: knowing that this problem doesn't happen when I am using the pdfLatex engine, but it happened only with the XeLatex engine. And I needed to use the XeLatex engine as all other problems are solved with it. I appreciate if you can give me some help in this.

Answer (score 2):

If LuaLaTeX is an option (I strongly recommend it) and your system is up to date, try the following preamble (the document body is the same). There are a few comments:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

% Basic setup for Arabic. With the second option
% counters are (visually) subsec.sec.chap.
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=counters]{babel}

% Load the locale and define a new counter for it, with
% a space-separated list.
\babelprovide[
  import, main,
  counters/alphabetic = واحد إثنان ثلاثة أربعة خمسة]
  {arabic}

\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

% Redefine the chapter ‘number’. It's now based on the
% counter just defined.
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\localecounter{alphabetic}{chapter}}

\setlocalecaption{arabic}{chapter}{المبحث}
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{contents}{قائمة المحتويات}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}%

% These are the setting in the OP. Note the overlapping
% because the chapter ‘number’ is long. 
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\bfseries}% <above-code>
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\title{\Huge\textsc{اللغة العربية}}
\author{سالم البوزيدي}
```

[image]

Comment: can you show me the full code?

Comment: I've extended a liitle bit the answer. Use this preamble with the original document body.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't compile in Arabic, nor from right to left, so I made a mockup of your document in another language (Spanish, using some fake Spanish words) to avoid English and check the settings.

1. `\pagenumbering{arabic}` should be after the first numbered chapter.
2. Using

   ```
    \usepackage{fmtcount}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\numberstring{chapter}} % or \Numberstring
   ```

you can change from chapter 1 to chapter one, etc. Note also the `\def\captionsspanish{%` to change the names from their default for the language.

3. Section and subsection alignment looks correct  after defining `\titlecontents{section}` and `\titlecontents{subsection}` (I reproduce the same setup you used for the chapter), but I don't know what happens to the writing from right to left!

[image: A]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{titletoc}%
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
[0pt]% <left>
{\bfseries}% <above-code>
{\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\titlecontents{section} % added <<<<
[0pt]% <left>
{}% <above-code>
{\sectionname\ :\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\titlecontents{subsection} % added <<<<
[0pt]% <left>
{\small}% <above-code>
{\subsectionname\ :\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\def\captionsspanish{% % added <<<<
    \def\chaptername{Xapítulo}% 
    \def\sectionname{Xection}% 
    \def\subsectionname{Xubec}% 
    \def\figurename{Figura}%
    \def\tablename{Tabla}%
    \def\partname{Parte}%}
    \def\contentsname{Contenido completo}%
    \def\listtablename{Lista de Tablas}%
}

\title{%
\Huge\textsc{Un titulo}
}
 \author{Mi Nombre}
 
 \usepackage{fmtcount}
 \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\numberstring{chapter}} % or \Numberstring

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{roman}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{5}

\chapter*{Presenta}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Presenta}

\chapter*{Agradece}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Agradece}

\chapter*{Resumen}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumen}


\chapter{Introduce}
\pagenumbering{arabic}  % move here <<<<

\section{A}
\subsection{aa}
\section{B}
\subsection{bb}
\subsection{cc}

\chapter{Desarrollo}

\chapter{Conclusiones}

%\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%[1]
%من ويكيبيديا، الموسوعة الحرة
%\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you add the numbers of sections and subsections in your code?

Comment: @W. Sam In the table of content or in the document ?